# Python match case dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.10

Getting the following error when using match case (python 3.10.4). I'm trying to use dictionary keys to make  the cases modular.

TypeError: called match pattern must be type

```
keys = { 'A': 'apple',
         'B' : 'banana'}
fruit = 'A'
match fruit:
    case keys.get('A'):
        print('apple')
   
    case keys.get('B'):
        print('Banana')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern is not an expression; it's a syntactic contract. You can't call a `dict` method as part of the pattern. You need to get the value *before* the `match` statement. Something like

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

values = SimpleNamespace(**{v: k for k, v in keys.items()})
match fruit:
    case values.apple:
        print('apple')
    case values.banana:
        print('Banana')
```

However, there's no particular reason to use a `match` statement here; a simple `if` statement would suffice:

```
if fruit == keys.get('A'):
    print('apple')
elif fruit == keys.get('B'):
    print('Banana')
```

---

Syntactically, the `match` statement is trying to treat `keys.get('A')` as a class pattern, with  `keys.get` referring to a type and `'A'` as a literal argument used to instantiate the type. For example, you could write

```
x = 6

match x:
    case int(6):
        print("Got six")
```

where the class pattern `int(6)` matches the value `6`.

Comment: Can't the attribute lookup `values.apple` involve calling a dict method (or even calculating a value on the fly)?

Comment: It could. If `values.apple` invoked `__getattr__` or `apple` was a property, for example, the return value would be used.